# Deploying firebase cloud functions using github actions

Tags: firebase, github, google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I'm trying to deploy my firebase cloud functions app using github actions:

```
name: Deploy

'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy_to_production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: install dependencies
        run: cd functions/ && npm install
      - name: deploy to production
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only functions
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

The step "deploy to production" is not successful. I activate debug mode and I don't actually receive any useful information:

```
##[debug]Evaluating: secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN
##[debug]Evaluating Index:
##[debug]..Evaluating secrets:
##[debug]..=> Object
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'FIREBASE_TOKEN'
##[debug]=> '***'
##[debug]Result: '***'
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'deploy to production'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: deploy to production
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Loading env
Run w9jds/firebase-action@master
  with:
    args: deploy --only functions
  env:
    FIREBASE_TOKEN: ***
/usr/bin/docker run --name w9jdsfirebaseactionv212_2c5197 --label 08450d --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e FIREBASE_TOKEN -e INPUT_ARGS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -e RUNNER_DEBUG -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/personalsite-backend/personalsite-backend":"/github/workspace" w9jds/firebase-action:v2.1.2 deploy --only functions
##[debug]Docker Action run completed with exit code 2
##[debug]Finishing: deploy to production
```

Am I missing something?

*Note: Locally I can deploy without any problem.*

Comment: Have you seen this issue: https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/134

Comment: @rethab Not actually! But thank you for sharing that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using `w9jds/firebase-action`, there's a known issue wherein if you use `uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master`, it tries to store what the CLI spits out and if it errors out and ends the action before it can echo it this might stop it from printing out the response. More information from the repository owner [**here**](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/134#issuecomment-1133799844).

Starting with version `v2.1.2`, you must replace this line:

```
uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
```

to this:

```
uses: docker://w9jds/firebase-action:master
```

More information [**here**](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action#alternate-versions).

---

Moreover, there is also an alternate solution to this by using [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) instead. See `yaml` configuration below:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Functions via github action
"on":
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  CI: false

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download deps
        working-directory: functions
        run: npm install

      - name: Deploy
        run: npx firebase-tools deploy
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Note: I've used `actions/checkout@v2` on the sample yaml above, but `v3` is now available.

Comment: Switching to your method of `npx firebase-tools deploy` finally got my environment variables working after hours of debugging  `w9jds/firebase-action@master`. Merci.

Comment: Using `FIREBASE_TOKEN` is deprecated. Do you guys have alternate solutions?

Comment: `GCP_SA_KEY: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}` is the way to go @AseerKTMiqdad